# What's 'undownvoted' doing on my rep page when I've done no such thing?

Tags: support, voting

Checking my rep this morning, I came across this:

[image: pic of undownvote]

I know that I haven't been doing any 'undownvoting' - in fact, I was in bed when this occured. Are there other things which can cause this to happen automatically?

Comment: MSO indicates that it *looks* like this could be the serial downvote reversal, but the fact that it's only one rep is throwing me.

Comment: Serial downvote reversal?

Comment: @shanodin Reversing when a user downvotes several of your posts in quick succession.

Comment: That's weird. I was browsing through the full list of questions and I know I did a bunch of downvoting, maybe there was a person with a lot of questions/answers/whatever in a row that I downvoted

Comment: I can't find the events in your rep history.

Comment: Is it maybe recovering rep from having downvoted a post that then got deleted?

Comment: @RavenDreamer that shows up as 'removed' doesn't it?

Comment: @shanodin Hm. It might. I'm not sure I've ever noticed either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were caught by a script that triggered on you for having performed what it identified as fraudulent serial downvoting on a user. In your case, the script reversed all of your downvotes at the same timestamp that your undownvote entries are listing. You received 1 reputation back for each of the reversed downvotes that you had cast on answers.

Comment: Whoa, that's never been my intended reason for downvoting :/ like I said, maybe someone had a bunch of stuff in a row on the full questions list. Feel like I've got a black mark on my name now :s

Comment: @shanodin It is a thing that can indeed happen, aye. But don't worry much on it - if you're innocent of any actual malice, then there's no actual black mark to be had.